# Circle in polar coordinates, center and radius

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates

If I have this formula of a circle in polar coordinates
$$r=R(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta))$$

Then how can I find the center and radius of it?
I've plotted it for $R=4$ 
[image: circle plot]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+{\pi \over 4}\right)$$another way is $$r^2=rR(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\implies x^2+y^2=Rx+Ry$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In the figure you drew, the circle crosses the $x$ and $y$ axes three times.
Those three crossings determine three points.
Three points determine a circle.